# Elegant way of adding constant value to numeric elements in list holding also None types

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve something very simple here which should be possible in a elegant one-liner but I can't figure out how:

Let's say I have a list `my_list = [1, None, 3, 4]` and want to add a constant `val = 3` to each of the numeric elements to obtain `my_list + val = [4, None, 6, 7]`:

This operation can be done using a somewhat bulky loop with a condition for `None` values:

```
my_list = [1, None, 3, 4]
val = 3
for idx, el in enumerate(my_list):
    if el is not None:
        my_list[idx] += val

print(my_list)
>>> [4, None, 6, 7]
```

However, I have the strong feeling that there must be a more elegant way of doing that. I attempted something along these lines:

```
my_list = list(map(lambda x: x+val, filter(None, my_list)))

print(my_list)
>>> [4, 6, 7]
```

But then the `None` elements are gone and I need to preserve them.

Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: my_list =[x+3 if x else x for x in my_list]

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan - That would keep `0` at 0 instead of `3`

Comment: True, we will have to check for none

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the following

```
[i + val if i is not None else i for i in my_list]
```

It simply adds the val to each element if it isn't none, otherwise it preserves the value

Comment: Ah, whenever I think I finally got the full potential of list comprehensions I learn something new. Perfect, thanks :)

Comment: @FlorianDrawitsch - Really it isn't anything to do with list comprehensions its just using a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/1324033) :)

Comment: Well, but if such ternary operators couldn't be used within list comprehensions, the solution would still require writing a loop or no?

Comment: @FlorianDrawitsch - A list comprehension is of the form `[<return_value> for <element> in <iterable>]` so all I'm doing here is setting the return value to the result of the ternary operator, you could've used the `map` function you were writing in a similar way to the other answer

Answer (score -1):

you can do this way with `lambda` function

```
val = 3
solution = list(map(lambda x: x if x is None else x+val, my_list))
```